# Is this a fire hazard?

Tags: electrical

I was going to change a light switch and repair some wall damage. When I started opening up the wall above the switch, I saw the electrical wire clamped to the stud[image]. I noticed black marks around it. Does this look like it might be a fire hazard and need an electrician. Personally I think so but I want to get some other opinions.

Answer (score 23):

Yes it is. You are correct. Call in an electrician.

Comment: If you think you're up to it, you can do a new run of wire yourself. Lots to consider for that operation, though.

Comment: @bib, that absolutely did NOT catch fire. What we are seeing is the tar from the cable. I've seen it a thousand times.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Thanks for the correction. Will delete the comment. But it still needs replacement (as you know).

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate: considering the age of the cable, there is likely much much more to repair, and its probably a good opportunity to do it all at once, which might be too much for him personally to diy.

Comment: @PlasmaHH -- agree completely that it's a complicated job. (Thus my disclaimer.) But with education, care, and a willingness to make numerous holes in the wall, (plus a few other things I've forgotten), electrical like this can be done DIY. I'm hoping that the OP will have a good sense of their attitude/skills/knowledge (complete with limitations, though it's sometimes hard to know what you don't know).

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate the problem is that electrical engineering is one of those things that can cost lives if done improperly. I really would hesitate to recommend someone do electrical work themselves without proper training. I mean, small things like replacing an outlet cover is something that a layman can do themselves without much issues, but anything like replacing an in-wall cable or adding new outlets really requires a professional. There's a reason that "electrical fire" returns over a million hits in Google News, and it's probably not incompetent electricians.

Comment: A cable that has been damaged enough to have a hole in the jacket is not unlikely to also have a reduced conductor cross section in that spot. Which translates to a great fire hazard.